# What's wrong with the following java code?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am getting some argument errors while compilation. don't know what wrong this.

I was expecting the output would be bj. since Class a doesn't have default constructor so at compilation time default constructor would be created by JVM. and the remaining output would be bj.  Am I missing something?

```
class a
{

    a(String b)
    {
        System.out.println("this is a");
    }
}
class b extends a
{
    b()
    {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}

class c extends b
{
    c(String j)
    {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
    public static void main(String...k)
    {
        new c("J");
    }
}
```

The error is shown below:

```
javac construct.java
construct.java:12: error: constructor a in class a cannot be applied to given ty
pes;
        {
        ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: The default constructor is only created if you don't write your own constructor. `a` has a constructor taking a `String` so there is no default constructor.

Comment: What are your compilation errors?

Comment: You should call super class constructor from within b's cunstructor : super("some String");

Comment: @kartic: had i used super in b , it would have been compiled successfully. but here I know that in a there isn't any default constructor. in cases where programmer doesn't kw this then what will b the solution

Comment: I doubt if this is possible. But I am curious is it practically possible - you are extending a class and you are not aware of super class constructor? Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since Class a doesn't have default constructor so at compilation time default constructor would be created by JVM

The default constructor is created **only if you don't define a custom constructor**.

Your IDE should have shown you the following message on `b()` declaration:

> There is no default constructor available in '*package*.a'

When you tried to instantiate `b`, it did an implicit call to `super()` but found only `a(String b)` instead of `a()`. As the error message says, `a(String b)` expected a `String` but got no arguments.

The solution is either to create the parameterless `a()` constructor or call the `a(String b)` constructor in class `b` constructor.

```
class b extends a
{
    b()
    {
        super(""); // call to class a constructor passing some string as argument
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree.Had I used super in b , it would have been compiled successfully. but here I know that in Class a there isn't any default constructor. in cases where programmer doesn't kw this(about there super class) then what will b the solution –

Comment: @kTiwari The programmer should know. If you are extending class A, the constructors of A should be documented.

Comment: @kTiwari Your IDE should show you the following error on b(): "There is no default constructor available in package.a". So the programmer has been warned of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*By convention you should name Java Classes in upper case letters*

When `new C("J");` is executed, it calls the constructor of `class C`. But as `class C` is extending `class B`, JVM will add

```
C(String j)
{
    super(); //added by JVM - calls the constructor of super class
    System.out.println("j");
}
```

So the constructor of class b is invoked and as it is also extending `class A`.

```
B()  
{  
   super();  //added by JVM
   System.out.println("b");
}
```

Now problem arises. As JVM will add default constructor in its implicit call. But there is no constructor defined with no-arguments. That's why you are getting an error. You can add `super("");` in constructor B to resolve the error or create a constructor with no parameters.